# What's the meaning of 'Chunk * _chunk = new (size) Chunk(size)'?

Tags: c++, jvm

There is a c++ code shown below:

```
Chunk * _chunk = new (size) Chunk(size);
```

I don't understand the first '(size)' following the 'new',What's the meaning of it?
The code above is from JDK8.

Comment: Find the overloaded `void * operator new(size_t, size_t)`.

Comment: [What uses are there for “placement new”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/222557/995714), [What is “placement new” and why would I use it?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called *placement new* syntax.  You might be able to find more about it using the technical name.  The arguments you ask about are passed to an overloaded `operator new` in addition to the normal computed size in bytes.